# List<Map<String, Object>> to Map<String, String[]>

Tags: list, dictionary, arraylist

I have a List of Map `List<Map<String, Object>>`. I want to move to `Map<String, String[]>`
Can someone please let me know how to convert?

```
        List<Map<String, Object>> currentList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        Map<String, Object> currMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        currMap.put("A", "ABC");
        currMap.put("B", "PQR");
        currMap.put("C", "XYZ");
        currentList.add(currMap);

        currMap.put("A", "123");
        currMap.put("B", "456");
        currMap.put("C", "789");
        currentList.add(currMap);

        currMap.put("A", "OOO");
        currMap.put("B", "ZZZ");
        currentList.add(currMap);
```

To-be  : 
"A", ["ABC", "123", "OOO"],
"B", ["PQR", "456", "ZZZ"],
"C", ["XYZ", "789", ""]

Answer (score 0):

One way using streams would be:

```
currentList.stream()
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

This would result in:

```
{A=[ABC, 123, OOO], B=[PQR, 456, ZZZ], C=[XYZ, 789]}
```

As a sidenote, the way you are generating `currentList` in the example does not result in a list of maps as you are probably expecting. As it is, you will end up with 3 references to the same map in the list.